# Listing active replications in couchdb 1.1.0

Tags: couchdb

I am bootstraping replications in couchdb by POSTing to localhost:5984/_replicate. This URL only accepts POST requests.

There is also a second URL: localhost:5984/_replicator, which accepts PUT, GET and DELETE requests.

When I configure a replication POSTing to _replicate, it gets started, but I can not get information about it. It is also not listed in _replicator.

- How can I get the list of active replications?
- How can I cancel an active replication?

Edit: how to trigger replications with the `_replicator` method.

Thanks to comments by JasonSmith, I got to the following solution: PUTting to `_replicator` requires using full url (including authentictation credentials) for the target database. This is not the case when using the `_replicate` url, which is happy getting just the name of the target database (I am talking here about pull replications). The reason, as far as I can tell, is explained [here](https://gist.github.com/832610) (see section 8, "The user_ctx property and delegations")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original API was a special URL, `/_replicate` where you tell Couch what to do and it tells you the result. However, the newer system is a regular database, called `/_replicator` and you create **documents** inside it telling Couch what to do. The document format is the same as the older `_replicate` format, however CouchDB will update the document as the replication proceeds. (For example, it will add a field `"state":"triggered"` or `"state":"complete"`, etc.)

To get a list of active replications, GET `/_active_tasks` as the server admin. For example (formatted):

```
curl http://admin:secret@localhost:5984/_active_tasks
[ { "type": "Replication"
  , "task": "`1bea06f0596c0fe6a1371af473a95aea+create_target`: `http://jhs.iriscouch.com/iris/` -> `iris`"
  , "started_on": 1315877897
  , "updated_on": 1315877898
  , "status": "Processed 83 / 119 changes"
  , "pid": "<0.224.0>"
  }

, { "type": "Replication"
  , // ... etc ...
  }
]
```

The wiki has instructions to [cancel CouchDB replication](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Cancel_replication). Basically, you want to specify the same source and target and also add `"cancel":true`.

Comment: That was very interesting, but it is still not solving all my problems. PUTting to `_replicator` is not working, whereas POSTing to `_replicate` is, with exactly the same document. In the logs I get: `Error starting replication '045020f93f9da91e1e6b609754b32a15+continuous+create_target' (document 'maintenance'): {unauthorized, <<"unauthorized to access database maintenance">>`. I prefer the `_replicator` method because it is a real database where I can easily manage my replications.